# File Category or Assets Folders for File Listings?

Tags: categories, assets, files

I'm using Assets and need to output a 'Resources' section listing various types of PDF's - Brochures, Technical Data, Operating Manuals with a 'category' nav to filter them.

I initially set them up as a category group and although I can apply categories to files using the native EE file manager, I cant seem to find any way of adding categories to files using Assets. Am I just missing something or is there a reason for this?

Would creating sub-folders in Assets and outputting the list using Asset template tags be a better method than using file categories and native tags? Can I filter by sub-folder?

Also, I noticed that if I create a sub-folder with more than a one-word title using Assets, the name is joined with an underscore i.e. 'Technical_Manuals'. Is there any way around this as obviously this wont be suitable front-end?

Finally, I seem to have hit the bug mentioned elsewhere where no files are being output front-end using Assets 2.1.2.

Comment: I'm doing something like this at the moment using Assets and a directory structure. However, as of Assets 2.1.2 there seems to be a bug that prevents output of files on the front-end. The issue is currently being looked at. ** and now I see that you have found this bug yourself ** :)

Comment: Hey; yeah it was your post where I saw it ;) Did you have any thoughts on the best way to do this?